# VBA Error with Recordset, .open doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, connection-string, adodb, recordset

In the With Statement I get an error on the line ".Open".

I tried to ensure that all the references are properly defined. what else could cause the problem?
Thanks for the expertise.

```
Option Explicit



Sub ConnectTODB2()
'early binding

 Dim CustomerTEST As ADODB.Connection
 Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
 Dim sqlText As String
 Dim ConStrAccess As String

 Set CustomerTEST = New ADODB.Connection
 ConStrAccess = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data           Source=C:\Users\YacubDavid\Desktop\CIC SOD TOOL 2011 GBW.mdb;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"



  CustomerTEST.Open ConStrAccess

  sqlText = "select * FROM 50 GBW People;"
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  rs.Open sqlText, CustomerTEST, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText



 'Worksheets.Add
 'Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs




  rs.Close
  CustomerTEST.Close
  Set CustomerTEST = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Would help to include the actual error message, but at a guess: `Set .ActiveConnection = CustomerTEST`

Comment: Can you post your connection string? If this isn't correct you won't ever successfully open the db connection.

Comment: Thank you for these replies already! I should add that I trying to connect to an access DB (2010) from excel. Also the error message says that it is a run time error - invalid SQL Instruction. DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, PROCEDURE or UPDATE is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Update 12/20: put [] around table name.   Another option is the following approach:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConnectTODB()
'early binding

Dim CustomerTEST As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim r As Range
Dim ConStrAccess    As String
Dim sqlText         As String

Set CustomerTEST = New ADODB.Connection
ConStrAccess = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                         "Data Source=C:\Users\YacubDavid\Desktop\xyz SOD TOOL 20x1 abc.mdb;" & _
                         "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
                         "Persist Security Info=False;"
CustomerTEST.Open ConStrAccess

sqlText = "select * from [50 GBW People];"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sqlText, CustomerTEST, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

'Worksheets.Add
'Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
CustomerTEST.Close
Set CustomerTEST = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for these replies already! I should add that I trying to connect to an access DB (2010) from excel. Also the error message says that it is a run time error - invalid SQL Instruction. DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, PROCEDURE or UPDATE is expected.

Comment: Is this error using your original code or the code I provided?  You need to look at the SQL syntax because that is bad. Please post your actual SQL

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I entered you text exactly. Now I get the error on the line: rs.Open sqlText, CustomerTEST, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText. The error message indicates that I have a syntax error in FROM command. I will post the actual code next.

Comment: You need to put brackets around the table name because it contains spaces. Anytime you reference a table or field or object where the name contains spaces or starts with a number you need brackets.